# Context menu long left click Qt

Tags: qt, click, contextmenu, long-integer

I try to have a context menu in Qt if we do a long press on a QGraphicsItemGroup. I have try basic thing like this:
my .h:

```
public:
    myclass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~myclass();

public slots:
    void contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::myclassClass ui;
```

my cpp:

```
 void myclass::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    if (event)
    {
        QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
        menu->addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));
        menu->show();
    }
    }
```

It's work, but only with right click and the menu don't appear near the click. And how to hae this only on a QGraphicsItemGroup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place your menu in the right position, i.e. in the place, where your context menu event occurred (where you clicked). The slot would look like:

```
void myclass::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu(this);
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 1", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 2", this));
    menu.addAction(new QAction("Action 3", this));

    // Place the menu in the right position and show it.
    menu.exec(event->globalPos());
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I have an error in "menu" menu.exec(event->globalPos()); it must be a class. And for have long left click you know how to do ?

Comment: It's work. You know how to do for have this menu, only on QGraphicsItemGroup and with long left click ?